# How to "trasform" an array of hash so that you can customize logic to access its data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to "trasform" the following array so that I can use my custom logic to access its data.

This is the original array from which I have to build a new one

```
[
  {
    "account" => {
       "id"   => 45, 
       "name" => "Test_name", 
       "..."  => ..."
     }
   }, 
   {
     "other"  => {
       "sub_other" => {...}
     }
   }
]
```

I would like to trasform the above array so that I can do in my controller something like

```
array_name[45]
# => {
       "name" => "Test_name", 
       "..."  => ..."
      }
```

*but only for the `account` hashs*. The `other` hash should remain untouched.

**How can I proceed to build the new array?**

Comment: If you're transforming one large data structure to another simply for convenient access to one piece of it in the controller, it is very inefficient. There's probably a better way. What is the first array coming from?

Comment: @Mark Thomas It is "account".

Comment: If Account is an ActiveRecord model, you don't need to create the first array at all. Use ActiveRecord methods like find() to get what you need.

Comment: @Mark Thomas I use also the 'Will_paginate' plugin that need an array to work. Also, how can I find an ActiveRecord using the 'where' statement and return an hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I think you are better off constructing a hash from account id to account data. Perhaps something like this will work:

```
arr = [
  {
    "account" => {
       "id"   => 45, 
       "name" => "Test_name", 
       "..."  => "..."
     }
   }, 
   {
     "other"  => {
       "sub_other" => "..."
     }
   }
]

account_hashes = arr.select {|item| item.keys.first == "account"}

answer = account_hashes.inject({}) do |acc, item| 
    acc[item["account"].delete("id")] = item["account"]
    acc
end
```